# Clicking links outside jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I Created a modal dialog box with jquery and made a little tweak that when the dialog loads.. i removed the overflow hidden property which disables the page scroll so that i can scroll the page..

i also removed a div with class "`ui-widget-overlay`" which creates that transparent gray behide dialog box and over the page.. now i can able to select text outside div.. right click on links and open them in new tab.. but i couldn't able to open the links outside the jquery dialog by just clicking them.

Comment: Why not just set modal to false when you initialize the dialog box?

Comment: @John cool man.. that worked.. post it in the answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set modal to false when you initialize the dialog box.

Ps - glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just set modal to false and it will do exactly what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ modal: true });
```

Comment: Really, a downvote on the correct answer without a comment? Stay classy.